# Erratic hole type resolution

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I recently found out that type holes combined with pattern matching on proofs provides a pretty nice Agda-like experience in Haskell. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, 
    UndecidableInstances, GADTs, TypeOperators #-}

data (==) :: k -> k -> * where
    Refl :: x == x

sym :: a == b -> b == a
sym Refl = Refl 

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data SNat :: Nat -> * where
    SZero :: SNat Zero
    SSucc :: SNat n -> SNat (Succ n)

type family a + b where
    Zero   + b = b
    Succ a + b = Succ (a + b)

addAssoc :: SNat a -> SNat b -> SNat c -> (a + (b + c)) == ((a + b) + c)
addAssoc SZero b c = Refl
addAssoc (SSucc a) b c = case addAssoc a b c of Refl -> Refl

addComm :: SNat a -> SNat b -> (a + b) == (b + a)
addComm SZero SZero = Refl
addComm (SSucc a) SZero = case addComm a SZero of Refl -> Refl
addComm SZero (SSucc b) = case addComm SZero b of Refl -> Refl
addComm sa@(SSucc a) sb@(SSucc b) =
    case addComm a sb of
        Refl -> case addComm b sa of
            Refl -> case addComm a b of
                Refl -> Refl
```

The really nice thing is that I can replace the right-hand sides of the `Refl -> exp` constructions with a type hole, and my hole target types are updated with the proof, pretty much as with the `rewrite` form in Agda.

However, sometimes the hole just fails to update:

```
(+.) :: SNat a -> SNat b -> SNat (a + b)
SZero   +. b = b
SSucc a +. b = SSucc (a +. b)
infixl 5 +.

type family a * b where
    Zero   * b = Zero
    Succ a * b = b + (a * b)

(*.) :: SNat a -> SNat b -> SNat (a * b)
SZero   *. b = SZero
SSucc a *. b = b +. (a *. b)
infixl 6 *.

mulDistL :: SNat a -> SNat b -> SNat c -> (a * (b + c)) == ((a * b) + (a * c))
mulDistL SZero b c = Refl
mulDistL (SSucc a) b c = 
    case sym $ addAssoc b (a *. b) (c +. a *. c) of
        -- At this point the target type is
        -- ((b + c) + (n * (b + c))) == (b + ((n * b) + (c + (n * c))))
        -- The next step would be to update the RHS of the equivalence:
        Refl -> case addAssoc (a *. b) c (a *. c) of
            Refl -> _ -- but the type of this hole remains unchanged...
```

Also, even though the target types do not necessarily line up inside the proof, if I paste in the whole thing from Agda it still checks fine:

```
mulDistL' :: SNat a -> SNat b -> SNat c -> (a * (b + c)) == ((a * b) + (a * c))
mulDistL' SZero b c = Refl
mulDistL' (SSucc a) b c = case
    (sym $ addAssoc b (a *. b) (c +. a *. c),
    addAssoc (a *. b) c (a *. c),
    addComm (a *. b) c,
    sym $ addAssoc c (a *. b) (a *. c),
    addAssoc b c (a *. b +. a *. c),
    mulDistL' a b c
    ) of (Refl, Refl, Refl, Refl, Refl, Refl) -> Refl
```

Do you have any ideas why this happens (or how I could do proof rewriting in a robust way)?

Comment: Aren't you expecting a bit much? Pattern matching on an equality proof is establishing a (bidirectional) equality. It's not at all clear where and in what direction you'd want it applied to the target type. For example, you could omit the `sym` calls in `mulDistL'` and your code would still check.

Comment: Quite possibly I'm expecting too much. However, in many cases it does work just as in Agda so it'd be still useful to figure out the regularities of the behavior. I'm not optimistic though, since the matter is likely deeply involved with the bowels of the type checker.

Comment: It's a bit orthogonal to your question, but you can pull off these proofs by using a set of equational reasoning combinators à la Agda. Cf. [this proof of concept](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/master/haskell/proofs/NatProofs.hs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate all possible such values, then you can write a function to do so, either with provided or specified bounds.

It may very well be possible to use type-level Church Numerals or some such so as to enforce creation of these, but it's almost definitely too much work for what you probably want/need.

This might not be what you want (i.e. "Except of using just (x, y) since z = 5 - x - y") but it makes more sense than trying to have some kind of enforced restriction on the type level for allowing valid values.

Answer (score -3):

It happens because the values are determined at run time. It can bring about a transformation of values depending on what are entered at run time hence it assumes that the hole is already updated.

Comment: Of course values are determined at runtime, but it has nothing to do with the question. The necessary information is already available from pattern-matching on a GADT.